# advertising.com display ad on my site 400 error

Tags: cookies, http-headers, ads, banner, malware

There is an RTB advertising.com placement on my site that is passing hundreds of cookies like this back to the adserver in the request header causing a 400 error:

```
],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "10059038",
              "value": "_52f06e17,2536076788,125^1647715^1183^0,0_",
              "expires": null,
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": false
            },
            {
              "name": "1011656",
              "value": "_52f1ac49,5585423647,840586^1654834^1183^0,1_",
              "expires": null,
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": false
            },
            {
              "name": "13130976",
              "value": "_52f1b1dd,6460543143,892975^1580686^1183^0,1_",
              "expires": null,
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": false
            },
            {
              "name": "16047785",
              "value": "_52f1b36b,7123606458,771487^1658460^1183^0,1_",
              "expires": null,
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": false
```

This is the request URL:

```
http://imp.bid.ace.advertising.com/click/site=878832/mnum=1676376/cstr=67942203=_52f2d06a,2005623046,878832_1676376_80_0,1_/xsxdata=$xsxdata/bnum=67942203/optn=64?trg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shobot.tv%2Fkirstie
```

Any idea why this is sending soooo many cookies. I am worried about this adpartner. Yo.